# Can someone explain this SQL Server code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen this code currently used in one of the stored procedures:

```
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN [ACTION] = 'INSERT' THEN ACTION END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE),
             MAX(CASE WHEN [ACTION] = 'UPDATE' THEN ACTION END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE),
             MAX(CASE WHEN [ACTION] = 'DELETE' THEN ACTION END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)) AS FINAL_ACTION
FROM #A
```

What it is doing it is using values in ACTION column and assigned them with some priority.

```
INSERT (1st priority)
UPDATE (2nd priority)
DELETE (3rd priority)
```

and creating a new column FINAL_ACTION based upon last_modified day value and the priority given to the ACTION column

For example, if my input data is like this

```
ID  ACTION  LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
------------------------------
1   INSERT  11-Feb
1   UPDATE  11-Mar
1   DELETE  14-Mar
2   UPDATE  12-Apr
2   INSERT  15-Apr
2   DELETE  19-Apr
3   UPDATE  2-Jan
3   DELETE  4-Jan
3   INSERT  7-Jan
```

then the output will look like this:

```
ID  ACTION  LAST_MODIFIED_DATE  FINAL ACTION
--------------------------------------------
1   INSERT  11-Feb             INSERT
1   UPDATE  11-Mar             INSERT
1   DELETE  14-Mar             INSERT
2   UPDATE  12-Apr             UPDATE
2   INSERT  15-Apr             INSERT
2   DELETE  19-Apr             INSERT
3   UPDATE  2-Jan              UPDATE
3   DELETE  4-Jan              UPDATE
3   INSERT  7-Jan              INSERT
```

So basically if the first value in the action column per id is of highest priority than its successive values then final action value will not get changed until something of highest priority comes after.

So can somebody please explain how this code is working?

Comment: @GuaravSingh . . . What requires explanation?  The logic seems pretty clear.  You can remove the `COALESCE()` and return the three columns separately.

Answer (score 0):

The expression contains 3 window functions call which are quite identical. Each of them searches the current and preceeding records that belong to the same `ID` for a specific action (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`). If the given action is found, then its name is returned by the window function, else `NULL` is returned.

So this...

```
MAX(CASE WHEN [ACTION] = 'INSERT' THEN ACTION END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
```

... will return string `'INSERT'` if the current record, or another record that has the the same `ID` and an earlier `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE`, has value `'INSERT'` in column `ACTION`.

Then, `COALESCE` acts like a filter that gives priority to the first searched action (`INSERT`), else falls back on the second (`UPDATE`), and finally on the third (`DELETE`).

The resulting behavior is what you correctly retro-engineered.